# On-the-fly data generation for benchmarking Beam

Tags: datasource, benchmarking, apache-beam

My goal is to benchmark the latency and the throughput of Apache Beam on a streaming data use-case with different window queries.

I want to create my own data with an on-the-fly data generator to control the data generation rate manually and consume this data directly from a pipeline without a pub/sub mechanism, i.e. I don't want to read the data from a broker, etc. to avoid bottlenecks.
Is there a way of doing something similar to what I want to achieve? or is there any source code for such use-case with Beam SDKs? 
So far I couldn't find a starting point, existing code samples use pub/sub mechanism and they assume data comes from somewhere.

Thank you for suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to On-the-fly data, one option would be to make use of GenerateSequence for example:

```
pipeline.apply(GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(RATE,Duration.millis(1000)))
```

To create other types of objects you can use a ParDo after to consume the Long and make it into something else:

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(PipelineOptionsFactory.create());
    p.apply(GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(2, Duration.millis(1000)))
    .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(1))))
    .apply(FlatMapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.kvs(TypeDescriptors.strings(), TypeDescriptors.strings()))
        .via(i -> IntStream.range(0,2).mapToObj(k -> KV.of(String.format("Gen Value %s" , i),String.format("FlatMap Value %s ", k))).collect(Collectors.toList())))
    .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String,String>, String>() {
      @ProcessElement
      public void process(@Element KV<String,String> input){
        LOG.info("Value was {}", input);
      }
    }));
p.run();
```

That should generate values like:

```
Value was KV{Gen Value 0, FlatMap Value 0 }
Value was KV{Gen Value 0, FlatMap Value 1 }
Value was KV{Gen Value 1, FlatMap Value 0 }
Value was KV{Gen Value 1, FlatMap Value 1 }
Value was KV{Gen Value 2, FlatMap Value 0 }
Value was KV{Gen Value 2, FlatMap Value 1 }
```

Some other things to keep in mind for your pipelines performance testing:

- The Direct runner is designed for unit testing, it does cool things like simulate failures, this helps catch issues which will be seen when running a production pipeline. It is not designed to help with performance testing however. I would recommend always using a main runner for those types of integration tests.
- Please be aware of the Fusion optimization [Link to Docs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.11.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/ParDo.html), when using a artificial data source like GenerateSequence you may need to do a GBK as the next step to allow the work to be parallelized. For the Dataflow runner more info can be found here:  [Link to Docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#fusion-optimization)
- In general for performance testing, I would recommend testing the whole end to end pipeline. There are interactions with sources and sinks ( for example watermarks ) which will not be tested in a standalone pipeline.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Regarding the data generator, I want to create data with KV pairs, a GBK will be applied and then a window function. Also, I want to tune the number of tuples that are generated per second. I think GenerateSequence is not sufficient. For the last point, I think what you want to say is I should test the pipeline with an external data source such as with Kafka?

Comment: You can use GenerateSequence to create a value and then in the next DoFn create your KV value. There are 2 places that you can expand the number of values being created. RATE is one place , the other is to use Multiple Output elements from the DoFn that you use to create the KV. Let me see if I can get time today to write a quick example and add to the answer. 

Yes Kafka or PubSub will work, always good to observe the system as a whole.

Comment: I have posted another question regarding the GenerateSequence code. I will be happy if you check it out from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112392/apache-beam-data-generator)